# Do microwaves heat polar molecules or molecules with polar bonds?

Tags: spectroscopy

IR is only absorbed my molecules with polar bonds 
regardless of the overall polarity of the molecule , what about Microwaves ?

Comment: Sure, water is one example.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the strength of the incident EMF. Pure $\ce{H2}$ can be [*ionized* by microwave radiation in multi-photon collisions](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Microwave_ionization_of_hydrogen_atoms), as well as being heated. Even nonpolar molecules have quantum fluctuations in the electron cloud, so they interact to some extent with n electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 2):

Microwave radiation can only excite rotational motion in molecules as this needs very little energy. IR excites vibrations which generally need more energy.  An oscillating dipole is needed for IR absorption thus HCl can absorb as can CH$_4$ as some of its vibrational motion can generate a transient dipole. Thus no permanent or oscillating dipole no absorption of the radiation, i.e. O$_2$ or N$_2$ molecules do not have IR or microwave absorption. (Raman scattering is used to measure their vibrational and rotational energy levels.)

In rotational motion a permanent dipole is required for photon absorption to occur. The rotating molecule is seen as an oscillating electromagnetic field by the radiation and if it is if the correct frequency energy is passed from the (microwave) radiation into the molecule, i.e. a photon is absorbed. The molecule now has one more quantum of rotational energy and the microwave photon no longer exists.